# There's a matrix C about a conic and a point vector x. Why the line l=Cx tangent to the conic on x?

Tags: linear-algebra, conic-sections

Here's a Conic: $ax^2+bxy+cy^2+dx+ey+f=0$,
and it is denoted by a matrix C:
$\left| \begin{matrix}  a \  \frac{b}{2}  \  \frac{d}{2}     \\
                        \frac{b}{2}  \   c      \ \frac{e}{2}   \\
                         \frac{d}{2}   \   \frac{e}{2}     \  f               \end{matrix} \right|.$

x is a point on the plane.

and the line $l=Cx$

Someone said that the l is tangent to the Conic and contact with the conic on x.

Can you tell me why?

Comment: See Theorem 9.1. of Perspectives on Projective Geometry by Jürgen Richter-Gebert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you define $r = \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$

Then the equation of the conic is $r^T C r = 0 $

The normal vector to the conic at the point $r_0 = [x_0, y_0, 1] $ is $ n = 2 C r_0 $

Therefore, the equation of the tangent plane at $r_0$ is $r_0^T C (r - r_0 ) = 0 $

And this reduces to  $ r_0^T C r = 0 $ because $r_0^T C r_0 = 0 $

Finally, we have to intersect this tangent plane with the plane $z = 1 $.  This can be done by letting the third element of $r$ be $1$, then the tangent line is

$r_0^T C r = 0 $

Answer (score 0):

Such a thing that when i post my question then i know the answer.
The slope of the tangent line $l$ is $\frac{\frac{\partial{C}}{\partial{x}}}{\frac{\partial{C}}{\partial{y}}}$

and the a in l:(a,b,c) equals the first row dot and x.
we know the value about artial derivative of square will doubled.
and in the matrix ,b is halfed.

so it only a Partial derivative